# Starting gedit from terminal produce error messages

Tags: gnome-terminal, debian-wheezy, gedit

When I start gedit from a terminal I get this output on the terminal:

```
tomas@debian:~$ gedit

(gedit:12617): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_list_store_set_column_types: assertion `priv->columns_dirty ==       0' failed
```

Can somebody explain what it is about. What can I do to correct it?

Some initial info:

```
tomas@debian:~$ dpkg --list gedit
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name             Version       Architecture  Description
+++-================-=============-=============-======================================
ii  gedit            3.4.2-1       i386          official text editor of the GNOME desk

tomas@debian:~$ uname -a
Linux debian 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.46-1+deb7u1 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Edit: There seem to be no need to panic about this. There has been no signs of bugs in the workings of gedit itself which starts normally. Also, I found a bug-report about nerely the same error message here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/1075354
and so it will be fixed sooner or later. Anyway, if somebody figure out what it is I would prefer not to get the critical message.

Comment: Does gedit launch anyway? If so, I wouldn't worry. It's probably something in gtk not specific to gedit.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/advanced-find/issues/detail?id=74

Comment: @JonathanBen-Avraham: Thanks. Accepted as a bug and fixed in a debian-coming version then. It means I would accept this as an answer if possible.

Comment: Or, maybe not. I dont have this advanced-find plugin and also I dont get that same kind of trace-back output. I get the feeling as @Yitzchak is saying, something related to gtk. gedit start normally but I cannot ignore this kind of stuff.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/205447/25656